# How to make VSCode produce beep sound while outputting the BELL character '\a'?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

The operating system is Ubuntu20.04. I used `echo -e '\a'` on the system terminal and the beep sound did play. So it has nothing to do with the device or the system settings.

When I ran the following code on VSCode,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<'\a';
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

no sound was produced. When I used the TERMINAL to display the output, it showed up as a visual bell next to the terminal's name. And when I used the OUTPUT instead, a tiny red-background icon with white text "BEL" was output.
[red icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od90p.png)

Or maybe there is something wrong with the configuration of my VSCode?

Comment: I am not sure, but do you have the `Terminal> Integrated: Enable Bell` enabled?

Comment: Yeah. But it shows up as a visual bell. I wonder if it can produce an auditory one?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be fixed in vscode v1.72.  An audio cue has been added for the terminal bell (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/001f7d5b4c20220ef7294f18616ad52df1039048).

With an associated setting, search for `Audio Cues` to enable.

Comment: Unfortunately for me the sound is too low compared to my music :-( What would be really awesome is if they could make the terminal popup and take focus on bell `*_*`

Answer (score 0):

Enable with:

```
"terminal.integrated.enableBell": true
```

Comment: But it does not make any sound, just shows for one second (no matter whether the terminal is the active one or not) a microscopic bell symbol near the terminal list. Pretty useless.

Comment: Where to add this?